# How to integrate $\cos^2x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

It seems like I am stuck on such a simple problem:

How to I find the antiderivative of $\cos^2x$?
I have tried partial integration, it doesn't seem to work (for me). Some help on how to integrate it would be nice.

Comment: Use $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1$.

Comment: Similar older question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628840/how-do-i-solve-int4-cos2x-dx

Comment: And [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29980/11619) explaining how to do ALL integrals $\int\cos^mx\sin^nx\,dx$.

Comment: I don't know the exact policy on when to mark a question as duplicate, but I wouldn't refer someone with this particular question to [Evaluating $\int P(\sin x, \cos x) \text{d}x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29980/159845). Having to go through the general Weierstrass substitution or reduction formulas is far too complicated for a basic integral like this; the standard approach for this one isn't even mentioned in that general answer. I agree that the link Martin Sleziak provides is indeed very similar although the OP here also tried integration by parts and got a specific answer for it.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that this specific question was mentioned as an example in [this discussion on meta about duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/how-close-a-match-we-need-to-close-a-recurring-question-as-a-duplicate/23508#23508).

Comment: See also: [How to evaluate $\int \cos^2x \ dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2349144)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the identity (e.g. solving from $\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2x-1$):
$$\cos^2 x = \frac{1+ \cos(2x)}{2}$$

---

Addendum: the previous hint will give you the easiest solution, but you mentioned an attempt with integration by parts - that would work too:
$$\begin{array}{rl}
\displaystyle  \color{blue}{\int \cos^2x \, \mbox{d}x} & \displaystyle
 = \int \cos x \, \mbox{d} \sin x \\[6pt]
& \displaystyle 
= \cos x \sin x - \int \sin x \, \mbox{d} \cos x \\[6pt]
& \displaystyle 
= \cos x \sin x + \int \sin^2 x \, \mbox{d}x \\[6pt]
& \displaystyle 
= \cos x \sin x + \int 1-\cos^2 x \, \mbox{d}x \\[6pt]
& \displaystyle 
= \cos x \sin x + x -  \color{blue}{\int \cos^2x \, \mbox{d}x} \\[6pt]
\Rightarrow \displaystyle 2 \int \cos^2x \, \mbox{d}x & \displaystyle
= \cos x \sin x + x  + C 
\end{array}$$
Then you divide by 2.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int (\cos x)^2\, dx=\int \frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}\, dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int \, dx+\frac{1}{2}\int \cos(2x)\, d(2x)\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)\right)+C=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sin(2x)}{4}+C$$